# Getting set of objects from NSSet using the HASH

Tags: objective-c

this is actually a question that i'd been trying to solve...

i need to implement this functionality in NSSet...

I know how hash tables and sets works.. and NSSet seems to store the pointer to the objects inside the hash table using the HASH as the index of that array... when more than one object falls in that hash.. it uses isEqual to detect which one of the objects is the member we search... that means...

HASH value => gives the index of the array of pointers in the hash table, and each one of those pointers points to an array (or some collection) that holds the objects with that hash (as it iterates over it to detect which object is the member)... this is a fairly common data struct...

My question is... is there a way to retrieve the array of objects that is being pointed by the hash table... i need ALL the objects that have the SAME HASH VALUE inside an NSSet...

i need this in order to quickly process proximity between points...

Is there a way? i know i can use a predicate using

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hash == %u",hash];
```

but this uses an enumeration and is not as fast as it needs to be (real fast)

Is there a way or should i create a HASH TABLE from scratch? (or use core foundation)

Thanks and sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the object in an array just call -allObjects, if you want all hashes, then you will have to iterate through them, because they are longs and can't be stored in an NSArray directly.

I had the idea to make a mock object that overrides its own hash, then you could search through an array for the index of this object that is pretending to be your object.

```
@interface MockHasher : NSObject{
    NSUInteger mockHash;
}

@property(assign,nonatomic,getter = hash,setter = setHash:)NSUInteger mockHash;
@end

@implementation MockHasher

@synthesize mockHash;

-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object{return YES;}
-(BOOL)isEqualTo:(id)object{return YES;}
```

@end

example:

```
NSSet * myset = [NSSet setWithObject:@(1)];
MockHasher * mockObject = [[MockHasher new] autorelease];
mockObject.hash = @(1).hash;
NSArray * allObjects = [myset allObjects];
NSUInteger i = [allObjects indexOfObject:mockObject];
id result = [allObjects objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"result = %@",result);
```

It is fragile, because it is depending on the array asking the object passed in for `isEqual:` rather than asking the iterated object... I don't know how reliable this is... but it worked in my test.

Comment: if it is implemented correctly each hash should be unique if the value is, and as such should only be added to a set once

Comment: what i'm trying to model here is a Hash "BAG" (as stated in the documents of CFSet) where you can get all values that have the same hash in an operation.. like ...  ([Set getWithHash:hash])... i can get that with a predicate but the performance is worying me

Comment: store them as a dictionary with the hash as the key.. or use the NSHashTable, or roll your own... NSHashTable probably isn't what you want... dictionary will impose an overwrite behavior if your hash alg isn't proper you could overwrite objects with different values

Comment: NSNumbered version of the hash as the key

Comment: @Heavy_Bullets ok I thought up a strange and fragile method that may be slower that iteration, ... but maybe not, I haven't profiled.

Comment: as i think about it.. it seems the solution is to implement a NSMutableDictionary, and overriding [setObject: forKey:] so it adds the object to an array before setting it (creating the array if it doesn't exist), after that, the KEY to the dictionary can be any key that defines the objects (i.e. HASH or some KEY) so in an example... pins on a map that share the same coordinates, share the same key for the dictionary....

Comment: i will mark this as the correct answer because it led me to the correct answer (it's also a lot of time since the question..)

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 6.0 and MacOS 10.5, you now have [an actual NSHashTable object](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSHashTable_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to work with.  Its modeled after NSSet, but instead is it's own thing.  [Here's some additional Apple documentation on Hash Tables](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Sets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000136-SW4), as well.

Comment: i'm new to this... i was thinking maybe the pointer functions would give me an array of pointers to the objects with the same hash?

Comment: upon further inspection, it seems that the pointer functions won't let me access the array at the hash index of the hashtable... maybe the solution is to implement a native c style hash myself